# Как сделать аддон для minecraft education edition / bedrock?

Tags: minecraft

Может кто-то сталкивался или имел опыт с созданием аддонов для игры minecraft bedrock, требуется сделать отдельный блок с необычным для майнкрафт строением:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данном этапе получается только заменить модель моба на свою, а хотелось бы создать полноценный блок. С возможностью взрыва или подачи редстоун сигнала от блока.
Модель блока в JSON формате:

```js
{
    "format_version": "1.12.0",
    "minecraft:geometry": [
        {
            "description": {
                "identifier": "geometry.unknown",
                "texture_width": 64,
                "texture_height": 64,
                "visible_bounds_width": 2,
                "visible_bounds_height": 1.5,
                "visible_bounds_offset": [0, 0.25, 0]
            },
            "bones": [
                {
                    "name": "bone",
                    "pivot": [0, 0, 0],
                    "cubes": [
                        {"origin": [-4, 0, -4], "size": [8, 3, 8], "uv": [0, 0]},
                        {"origin": [-5, 0, -3], "size": [1, 3, 6], "uv": [16, 11]},
                        {"origin": [4, 0, -3], "size": [1, 3, 6], "uv": [8, 14]},
                        {"origin": [-5, 0, -3], "size": [1, 3, 6], "uv": [0, 11]},
                        {"origin": [-3, 0, -5], "size": [6, 3, 1], "uv": [24, 0]},
                        {"origin": [-3, 0, 4], "size": [6, 3, 1], "uv": [0, 23]}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "bone2",
                    "pivot": [0, 0, 0],
                    "cubes": [
                        {"origin": [-1, 3, 2], "size": [2, 1, 1], "uv": [0, 6]},
                        {"origin": [-1, 3, -3], "size": [2, 1, 1], "uv": [0, 11]},
                        {"origin": [2, 3, -1], "size": [1, 1, 2], "uv": [0, 0]},
                        {"origin": [-3, 3, -1], "size": [1, 1, 2], "uv": [0, 3]},
                        {"origin": [-2, 3, -2], "size": [4, 1, 4], "uv": [18, 20]}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Лучше почитайте статьи на тематических сайтах. Или возьмите исходники чужого готового аддона и посмотрите как там сделано